# routerOnActivate on Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a component like this on Angular 2 application, but it no run on Angular 4, the RouteSegment do not work. How to do it on Angular 4?

```
export class CallBackLoginComponent {

private user: User = new User();
private showLoading: boolean = false;
private errorMessage: string = null;

constructor(private _loginService: LoginService,
    private _router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private _comunication: Comunication,
    private _routerParams: RouteSegment) {
};

//Parametros recebidos atraves da rota /user/token
routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment) {
    var token = {token: curr.getParam('token')};
    if (token != null) {
        this.showLoading = true;
        this.errorMessage = null;

        this.userService.vldToken(token).subscribe(
            result => this.onLoginResult(result),
            error => this.onLoginError(error)
        );
    }
    else{
        this._router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}
```

Comment: a2.hubwiz.com/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html Do some search  before posting

Comment: This looks more like a prerelease of Angular 2? If so, the router changed between the pre-release/beta/rc of Angular 2 and its release. I don't believe that any of this was changed in Angular 4.

Comment: Yes its is a prereleaseof Angular 2

Comment: Sreemat I do. Your link is down.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That version of the router was used in the earlier Releases Candidates. There was a major rewrite of the router (updating it to the version 3) between RC 4 and RC5.

Now you will have to subscribe to route.params and get the key token that you're looking for.

```
export class CallBackLoginComponent implements OnInit {

   private user: User = new User();
   private showLoading: boolean = false;
   private errorMessage: string = null;

constructor(private _loginService: LoginService,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private _comunication: Comunication) {
};

ngOnInit() {
   this._route.params().subscribe(params => this.routerOnActivate(params['token']);
}

//Parametros recebidos atraves da rota /user/token
routerOnActivate(token: string) {
    if (token != null) {
        this.showLoading = true;
        this.errorMessage = null;

        this.userService.vldToken(token).subscribe(
            result => this.onLoginResult(result),
            error => this.onLoginError(error)
        );
    }
    else{
        this._router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear, Thanks for you help. Look , can i use a route.params like a ActivatedRoute type ?

Comment: another way of do it
on ngOnInit()  
const token = this._route.snapshot.params.token
token will have the parameter passed in your route

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

1. using `canActivate` functionality of router .

app.routing.ts

```
import { HomeComponent } from './user/home.component';
import { AppGuard } from './app.gaurd';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
const usrRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user/:token', component: UserComponent
    , canActivate: [AppGuard]
  },
  {
    path:'home',component:HomeComponent
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];

export const userRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(usrRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

app.guard.ts

```
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class AppGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  /**
   * 
   * @param route  current route object
   * @param state  route state
   */
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot
   ) {
    let paramJSON = route.paramMap['params'];
    if (paramJSON['token']) {
    let token = paramJSON['token'];
    if (token && token != null) {
     // do your operation or api call to validate token 
     return true;
    } else {
      /**
       *  return url , redirect where u want to redirect after failure 
       */
       this.router.navigate(['/home'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
     }
     return false;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts : import AuthGard & routings to Module

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        UserComponent,
        HomeComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpModule,
        BrowserModule,
        userRouting,
      ],
      providers: [
        AppGuard
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

2. by using `ngOnInit` function

here we don't need to use canActivate, use this code within your component ....

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-user',
    templateUrl: './user.component.html'
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {


    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.checkRouteParam_();
    }

    /**
        *  this will be called every time route changes
           so you can perform your functionality here
        */
    public checkRouteParam_() {
        this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            this.validateRouteParam();

        });
    }


    public validateRouteParam() {
        let token = this.route.snapshot.params['token'];
        if (token) {
            // do your operation or api call to validate token 
            return true;

        } else {
            let failureRetUrl = "/home";
            /**
             *  return failureRetUrl , redirect where u want to redirect after failure 
             */
            return this.router.navigate([failureRetUrl]);
        }

    }

}
```